# I need help to draw an icosahedron 3D object in an UIKit app

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit

Although I am quite experienced with most frameworks in iOS, I have no clue when it comes to 3D modelling. I even worked with SpriteKit, but never with something like SceneKit.

Now a customer wants a very ambitious menu involving a 3D object, an 'icosahedron' to be exact. I want it to look something like this:

[image: Icosahedron shape example]

So I just want to draw the lines, and grey out the 'see-through' lines on the back. Eventually I want the user to be able to freely rotate the object in 3D.

I already found this question with an example project attached, but this just draws a simple cube: [Stroke Width with a SceneKit line primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705321/stroke-width-with-a-scenekit-line-primitive-type)

I have no clue how to approach a more complex shape.

**Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!** I don't even need to use SceneKit, but it seemed like the best approach to me. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What about using OpenGL ES?

Comment: SceneKit uses OpenGL ES underneath and makes it simpler to use I think. Why use the more complicated OpenGL when I could use SceneKit which is easier to understand? I don't know anything about both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to build an icosahedron you can use `SCNSphere` and set its  `geodesic` property to `YES`.

Using shader modifiers to draw the wireframe (as described in [Stroke Width with a SceneKit line primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705321/stroke-width-with-a-scenekit-line-primitive-type)) is a good idea.

But in your case lines are not always plain or dotted — it depends on the orientation of the icosahedron. To solve that you can rely on `gl_FrontFacing` to determine whether the edge belongs to a front-facing or back-facing triangle.

Comment: Wow thanks! I'm really impressed by your answer. It looks like you provided a solution for all my requirements! This week I am going to try this out myself to see if it really works. I will accept your answer as soon as I get it to work!

Comment: It looks like a SCNSphere is indeed the way to go! I accepted your answer. But can you maybe also explain how to use shader modifiers to draw the wireframe?